# How do i view the post json data in a web browser?

Tags: java, php, json, netbeans

I am working on a mini project(REST application) in which I require to post json data from java to php and display it. But I have not been able to accomplish this task even after trying for the past 2 days. So I made a separate file to test out how this works.

The following is my *.java* file which I run in netbeans

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class NewClass {
public static void main(String[] args) {   
String json = "{\"message\":\"This is a message\"}";

HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
try {
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://localhost/test/somesite.php");
        StringEntity params =new StringEntity("message=" + json);
        request.addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.setEntity(params);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
        // handle response here...
        System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
        EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
}  
}
```

The following is my *.php*(somesite.php) file which is in *C:\xampp\htdocs\test*. I use xampp.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["message"]) && !empty($_POST["message"]))
{
    print_r($_POST);
    $json_string = $_POST["message"]; 
    $json = json_decode($json_string);
    print_r($json);
}
?>
```

When i run the *.java* file in netbeans i get the following [output window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfnWE.png)

But when I refresh my *.php* page in the browser I get nothing, I get a [blank page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7c3x.png)
How do I get the json data that I post from my *.java* to my *.php* to display in a browser?

Any help appreciated, I am new to json and php. Thankyou.

Comment: Are you sure it's a blank page and not an error page? Check your error logs, and check the browser console. Try echoing out some details along the way (`var_dump($_POST);` before your isset)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working as would be expected.

When you are accessing the page in the browser that is a `GET` request and should show nothing because you are checking `POST` which is empty/not set.

Likewise your java request makes it to the page as a `POST` request and you are seeing the output of PHP's `print_r` in the console hence the `=>` and `stdClass`.

To see this in the browser you would need to make the request to a service from PHP to Java. You are currently trying to push from java and then look at it in the browsers which is not possible. Essentially your code is backwards.

PHP has `curl` support for making request or you can use the very popular GuzzleHTTP library for that.

Comment: Thankyou for your helpful answer, Could you point me to a direction where i can learn about using  _curl_ to make requests from maybe some examples or demos.

Comment: It is pretty readily out there on google https://www.google.com/search?q=Using+curl+to+access+API&oq=Using+curl+to+access+API&aqs=chrome..69i57.10416j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8. I would recommend GuzzleHTTP thought curl can be a pain.